# Retrieve value associated with C pointer in Julia MPI

Tags: parallel-processing, mpi, julia

**How does one retrieve the value associated with a pointer in Julia?**

For example,

```
import MPI

function  main()
    MPI.Init()

    comm = MPI.COMM_WORLD
    println("Hello from processor $(MPI.MPI_GET_PROCESSOR_NAME) rank $(MPI.Comm_rank(comm)) of $(MPI.Comm_size(comm))\n")
    MPI.Barrier(comm)

    MPI.Finalize()
end

main()
```

produces the output

```
Hello from processor Ptr{Void} @0x00007fc29b392290 rank 1 of 2
Hello from processor Ptr{Void} @0x00007f7759d9f290 rank 0 of 2
```

including the raw pointers rather than processor names.

Answer (score 2):

If you are sure that it's a C-style (NUL-terminated) string encoded as UTF-8 (or ASCII) you could try:

```bash
unsafe_string(Ptr{UInt8}(MPI.MPI_GET_PROCESSOR_NAME))
```

Read the doc (https://docs.julialang.org/en/latest/base/strings/index.html#Base.unsafe_string) and be careful! Citing from the docs:

> This function is labeled "unsafe" because it will crash if `p` is not
>   a valid memory address to data of the requested length.